# Can't Update Beta App on Google Play Store

Tags: testing, google-play, beta

I want to test new version app with my testers. I created close test channel and typed tester's email addresses. The beta app was published. App name was changed on Google Play Store to " (beta)". But we can't update. There is no update button on Google Play Store. There are two buttons, open and remove. How can we update the beta app to test on Google Play Store?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know update is not supported. You either have to go live with the app or remove the current version and create new beta.

Comment: I am surprised. I want to test updating time operations. Read current databases and get the new features. I guess I should make 2 apk, old version and new version. I should try to update with apk file.